# Why does Android Service starts in wrong order?

Tags: android, service

I start a `service` in `onCreate()` of my activity, the code is below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    application = (OldBookApplication) this.getApplicationContext();
    util=new SharePreferenceUtil(LoginActivity.this, Constants.SAVE_USER);
    Utils.getScreenWidth(this);
    Utils.getScreenHeight(this);
    Utils.getScreenDensity(this);
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
    if (isNetworkAvailable())
    {

        Intent service = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, GetMsgService.class);
        startService(service);
    }
    else
    {
        //show("no network");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    checkServer();

    autoLogin();
}
```

and `checkServer()` function is below:

```
private void checkServer()
{
    if(!application.isClientStart())
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        LoginActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

my Service code below:

```
public class GetMsgService extends Service
{
    private OldBookApplication application;
    private Client client;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private boolean isStart = false;
    private Notification mNotification;
    private Context mContext = this;
    private SharePreferenceUtil util;
    private MessageDB messageDB;              //<-----

    private BroadcastReceiver backKeyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setMsgNotification();
        }
    };
    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case MSG:
                ......
            }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()     
{
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
    messageDB = new MessageDB(this);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Constants.BACKKEY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(backKeyReceiver, filter);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    application = (OldBookApplication) this.getApplicationContext();
    client = application.getClient();
    application.setmNotificationManager(mNotificationManager);
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flag, startId);
    util = new SharePreferenceUtil(getApplicationContext(),
            Constants.SAVE_USER);
    isStart = client.start();
    application.setClientStart(isStart);
    if (isStart)
    {
        ClientInputThread in = client.getClientInputThread();
        in.setMessageListener(new MessageListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void Message(MessageEntity msg) 
            {

                if (util.getIsStart())
                {
                    if (msg.getType() == MessageType.MESSAGE)
                    {
                        ......
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent broadCast = new Intent();
                    broadCast.setAction(Constants.ACTION);
                    broadCast.putExtra(Constants.MSGKEY, msg);
                    sendBroadcast(broadCast);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (messageDB != null)
        messageDB.close();
    unregisterReceiver(backKeyReceiver);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(Constants.NOTIFY_ID);
}
```

}

the running order of the program is 
      `onCreate()` of the LoginActivity --->`onResume()` of LoginActivity 
                                        --->`autoLogin()`function 
                                        --->`onCreate()` of SettingActivity 
                                        --->`onCreate()` of the GetMsgService
                                        --->`onStartCommand()` of GetMsgService

I want to know that why the `onCreate()` of the GetMsgService was not called at `startService()`? And the same question for the SettingActivity.

Comment: Can we have your service code?

Comment: @ChintanRathod I have updated it.Thank you!

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.42. Does it have any effects on this?@ChintanRathod

Comment: Nope... There is no relation with code of your project with Android Studio. Service is independent to gradle my friend. Try out some example where you put logs or toast so that you can find the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `startActivity()` and `startService()` operate asynchronously. Calls to those methods returns before the requested action is performed.  Conceptually, the requested operations is added to a system event queue and executed at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start your Service in Application class which extends Application so when your
```

application is started your service is start firstly.

Comment: I have had tried to move `startService()` to the `onCreate()` of the  `Application`, but it also ran `checkServer()` first.